# Pandas: check if df.loc with multiple conditions will return an error

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code in my python/pandas project:

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 'Total', 'AAA'] = df.loc[(df['Category'] == 'Category_A') & (df['Sub_Category'] == 'AAA'), 'Quantity'].values
```

Assuming the df has a 'Category_A' and 'Sub_Category' of 'AAA' this works great. However there could be cases where either/or of these are missing depending on the imported data. That raises a KeyError.

Right now I have a clunky work-around where I manually set the value to zero but it requires me to have foreknowledge of which datasets are going to cause the problem, which in the long-run isn't a good solution.

Any thoughts?

Comment: In cases where those columns don't exist, how do you want the code to behave? Just assume `False` for every row?

Comment: Basically what I want is to tell it if either of these values are missing from the given columns, set the value to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with

```
df.loc[(df['Category'] == 'Category_A') & (df['Sub_Category'] == 'AAA')&(df['A'] == 'Total'), 'AAA'] = df['Quantity']
```